# Yocto: How restore missing sstate manifests after "do_cleansstate"

Tags: yocto, bitbake

To delete the sstate, I ran the command `bitbake -c do_cleansstate <receipe>`. Then I deleted the folder "tmp/sstate-control" by hand.
If I now want to rebuild via `bitbake <receipe>`, I get the following message:

> core-image-full-cmdline-1.0-r0 do_prepare_recipe_sysroot: The sstate manifest for task
> 'XXXX:populate_sysroot' (multilib variant '') could not be found.

Followed by a list of missing manifests "populate_sysroot".

What is left for me to do but rebuild everything?
Is there a command or way to restore the missing manifests?
Shouldn't `do_cleanstate` actually work cleanly?

I randomly tried the `do_populate_sysroot` command, among others.

Answer (score 3):

"cleansstate" wipes out files in SSTATE_DIR, not the sstate-control directory which is used to control files in tmpdir and individual workdirs. You should never touch sstate-control by hand, certainly not delete it. The only sane way to recover now is to wipe out TMPDIR completely and rebuild.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have now learned not to touch sstate-control`. There I was probably a little too hasty.

Answer (score 1):

My experience is that the best is to use `bitbake -c cleanall <receipe>` then you can restart the building with `bitbake <receipe>` command.

[What does BitBake Cleanall do?](https://thequickadvisor.com/what-does-bitbake-cleanall-do/)

> Removes all output files, shared state (sstate) cache, and downloaded
> source files for a target (i.e. the contents of DL_DIR).